# ngResource retrive unique ID from POST response after $save()

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, ngresource

So I have a Resource defined as follows:

```
angular.module('questionService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('QuestionService', function($http, $resource) {
    var QuestionService = $resource('/api/questions/:key', {}, {
        query: {
            method:'GET', 
            isArray:true,
        },
        save: {
            method: 'POST',

        }
    });

    return QuestionService
});
```

And later on I take some form input and do the following

```
var newQ = {
    txt: $scope.addTxt
};

QuestionService.save(newQ)
```

The server responds to the POST request both by reissuing the JSON for the object and setting the location header with the new unique ID.  The problem is that Angular is not saving that returned JSON or the location header into the object and it is not getting set with the ID from the server for future operations.  I've tried a number of things such as:

```
transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
    locationHeader = headersGetter().location;
    key = locationHeader.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    data.key = key;
    return data;
}
```

However the returned data item doesn't seem to be getting used.  Am I missing something?  This seems like a pretty common use case for interacting with a REST api.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a success handler to assign the new id to `newQ` manually:

```
QuestionService.save(newQ, function(data) {
    newQ.id = data.id;
});
```

But there is a better to achieve the same. Because your `QuestionService` is a resource class object, you can instantiate your `newQ` like this:

```
var newQ = new QuestionService({text: $scope.addTxt});
```

Then, call `$save()` of `newQ`:

```
newQ.$save();
```

Now `newQ` should have the new id returned by the server.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't even realize this syntax was available.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent $save from overwriting the resource with the response? For example I have a user resource $scope.user. If I call $scope.user.$save() and the server responds with "Success", ng-resource will set $scope.user to the word "Success". It there any way to prevent that? My backend just returns the ID of the new user, which I'd like to update manually in the success callback: $scope.user.id = response.id, I dont wan't the extra overhead of passing the entire user object back in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I have Asp.Net server with WebApi2 running, i use Ok(number) to return content, and it return for example '6' as result. once it return, the angular show an object containing promise and state, and prototypes and a deep repeated hierarchy, but no value, no '6'.
So i went to see where the data goes, for seeing where the data is i define a transform, and i see awo the data, but it's not a json...

later i change it to following, and now i have a obj in my success function, which has sub property called 'returnValue' (as i defined), and this object hold my value.

```
transformResponse: function(data, header){
    var obj={};
    obj.returnValue=angular.fromJson(data);
    return obj;
},
```